# Using Response.status from API in Authenticating User Login in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a login function in my Angular 2 app, and after unsuccessfully trying a few authentication methods with our API, I have landed on one that works. Basically, the way it works is like this: if the inputed "username" and "password" are found in our mongoDB collection, the API will send a 200 status. If not, it doesn't. So that's what I'm checking: if I have a username and password inputed that returns a 200 status, then go ahead and login the user. Does this seem like a workable way to handle this? Is checking against a response.status a legitimate way to handle this?

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const u = encodeURIComponent(username);
    const p = encodeURIComponent(password);
    this._url = `https://api.somesite.com/v0/staff/login/${u}/${p}?apikey=somekey`;
    console.log(this._url);
    return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const user = response.json();
            if (user && (response.status = 200)) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            } else {
                console.log('User ' + this.username + ' not recognized by API...');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You can use the HTTP status code to indicate success or failure of the login operation but how do you plan on verifying that subsequent requests are from an authenticated user? Just saving something in localStorage is usually not enough. How will you handle session expiration? Or permission revocation? The server usually returns some kind of token that you store locally (e.g. in localStorage) then you add that token to the headers of all subsequent requests so that the server can verify the validity of the token *for each request*.

Comment: Also, why do you pass the username and the password *twice* to the backend? (once in the URL, and once in the payload)

Comment: Good points. I will look into that. Thanks AF.

Comment: Also, it is very unsecure to expose passwords in HTTP requests like this... use some type of ssl or encryption at least.

Comment: @Jim Actually, if you look above, it's "https".